# Laravel Forge & Digital Ocean Add SSH Port

Tags: digital-ocean

I accidentally deleted port 22 from the firewall configuration on Laravel Forge.

I have important information in the database that I need to keep.

Is there any way of getting my server back working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [console on the control panel](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-digitalocean-control-panel) (see the section about "Access"), that will give you SSH access where you can add port 22 back into the firewall.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem recently, when I changed the SSH port as a security measure without updating the firewall settings beforehand.

It turns out that Forge automatically configures iptables and I was able to resolve the situation using the ufw interface with these steps:

1. As in phillbaker's answer, I used the Digital Ocean Console Access to login to the droplet.
2. Then, I configured ufw to open the new SSH port I've configured with `sudo ufw allow ##` where ## is the new port number. In your case you'll want to do `sudo ufw allow 22` to reopen port 22.
3. In my case, I wanted to close the now unused port 22 so I issued `sudo ufw delete allow 22`. You don't want to do this in your situation just FYI.

You can find out more about ufw [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/firewall.html).